# How to add three values into a database in a single foreach loop, using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have an input form with two values as a key, constructed this way:

```
<input name="verificarPago['.$x['pagoID'].'-'.$x['userID'].']" type="text">
```

So, the HTML would look like, for example, like this:

```
<input name="verificarPago[4-10]" type="text">
```

Besides that I have the value that the user can type, for example "Juan".

**The inputs are created programmatically, and I want to save them each three values (in the example: 4, 10, Juan) into a database.**

So, when the user submits the form, I thought on using `foreach` in order to access the elements in that array, but my problem is: How may I explode the keys to access the two values separately?

I've tried this (I'm not taking into account security now, I'm trying to prove the concept):

```
              $verificar = $_POST['verificarPago'];
              foreach ($verificar as $pago => $curso) {
//I'm pretty much stuck here. 
                  $verificar= array_flip(explode("-", $verificar));

//I want to insert the three items into the database
                  $verificarPago = "INSERT pagosVerificados SET userID = '$usuario', pagoID = '$pago', cursoID = '$curso'";
                  $cargarPago = mysqli_query($conectar, $verificarPago);

              }
```

I've tried adding to the form another input type, so the values wouldn't be together, but that way I should do a foreach inside a foreach and that renders duplicated results (and with errors as well).

Comment: Your query doesn't include a field for the "Juan" value - what column is that supposed to go into?

Comment: is one of the three values to be inserted into the database. I put Juan just as an example.

Comment: Why don't you not use a foreach? An example of this would just be sanitizing the $_POST input and inserting the $_POST value to sql individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without addressing any architectural issues, adding error-checking, or addressing security problems, here's how to do what you're asking for

```
$verificar = $_POST['verificarPago'];
foreach ($verificar as $ids => $text) {
    list($pagoID, $cursoID) = explode("-", $ids);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO pagosVerificados (userID, pagoID, cursoID, someVarcharField)
                      VALUES ($usuario, $pagoID, $cursoID, '$text');";
    $cargarPago = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);

}
```

This is a tad inefficient though - executing an insert for every iteration. Since mysql supports bulk inserts, you can modify the generation of the query to leverage that.

```
$verificar = $_POST['verificarPago'];
$rows = array();

foreach ($verificar as $ids => $text) {
    list($pagoID, $cursoID) = explode("-", $ids);
    $rows[] = "($usuario, $pagoID, $cursoID, '$text')";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO pagosVerificados (userID, pagoID, cursoID, someVarcharField) VALUES "
               . implode(',', $rows)
               . ";";
$cargarPago = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
```

Now it's just one round-trip to the database

Comment: Get my vote for generating the multi-insert instead of re-structuring the loop.

Comment: Thank you, and the ulti-insert was brilliant. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, -1 for the first bit. +1 for the second bit

Answer (score 1):

This is a bizarre way of passing values over POST. But, to expand on Peter's answer and address the glaring security issues, you can also use prepared statements. They're designed to be prepared once and then executed multiple times so are perfect for the job.

```
$verificar = $_POST['verificarPago'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO pagosVerificados (userID, pagoID, cursoID, someVarcharField) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
$stmt = $conectar->prepare($sql);

foreach ($verificar as $ids => $text) {
    list($pagoID, $cursoID) = explode("-", $ids);
    $stmt->bindParam("iiis", $usuario, $pagoID, $cursoID, $text);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

It's been years since I've worked with mysqli, but this should do the trick. You'll want to include some error checking in there as well.